# Reactivity in vue js v-model when updating value via JS/some plugins

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm currently having some troubles understanding how VueJS' v-model reactivity works.

I have a select plugin which helps me style select fields, but it changes the select field value via JS of course, the problem is that it never triggers v-model to update its value, the same happens if I try to `document.getElementById('field').value = 'whatever'`, v-model just won't update if I do that, it will only update when I type directly in the field or when I click the real select field.

As I've read, it seems that Vue only listens to the `input` event to trigger its reactivity, and when I simply change the value of the field with JS the event will  not be fired, though not updating the variable's value.

I really need to understand this more deeply and have a best way to handle this kind of problems when they happen next. What would be the best solution in this case where I don't have control over the plugin's events? How could I make Vue listen when the value is changed dynamically and never have this problems again?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this is going to help, but did you have a look at form input components?
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events

Your input component must emit the event back to the outside to make it update value of the `v-model` associated with the component.

You might also want to check `watchers` if you're having trouble figuring out whether the input value has changed
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

I hope this help.

Comment: I think this doesn't help me much. I don't have an input component, I'm using a jQuery plugin which styles my `select` field, I also use another plugin for a date pick which is bound to another input and changes its value, both don't update the v-model when the values changes. I've managed to make the datepicker work by adding `.lazy` to the `v-model`, but that doesn't seem to work on the select, and it also doesn't look like it's right. Any clues?

Comment: Oh I see - so it's a battle between the `jQuery` and `VueJs`. Check if the jQuery plugin dispatches any events - you could listen to these events from within the Vue component and then update value accordingly.

Comment: I see, I wanted to avoid this approach as it seems too manual, but I don't know if there's another way out. I'll try that, thanks :)

Comment: No problem at all - hope you'll get to resolve the issue.